gcc unexpected C static_assert error: expression in static assertion is not constant
I have some C code which builds OK with gcc-11 and earlier but not gcc-12 and later.
This illustrates the problem (this isn't the actual code I'm working on):
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

// forward testfunc declaration
void testfunc(int testvar);

int main()
{
  static_assert(((uintptr_t)testfunc != 0), "error!!");
}

// testfunc definition
void testfunc(int testvar) {}


see also: https://godbolt.org/z/vMf31zoaT
With gcc-12, if I move the testfunc() definition before main(), then it builds OK.
But with testfunc() after main(), I get the build error:
error: expression in static assertion is not constant
I don't understand why I get this error as the function address is constant.
This occurs several times in the existing code I'm working on. I could fix it by modifying the code, but I'd prefer not to as it would mean a lot of changes. Any ideas how to fix this?
Just to be clear: the code above illustrates the problem. The actual code I'm working on uses static_assert in a macro to detect if a const function pointer is set to NULL in error, but it gets the same error with gcc-12.

That code doesn't make any sense... Pointers to functions can never be null (which you're checking for).

As for the error, with a forward declaration the compiler knows the function exists somewhere, but it doesn't known where. Therefore you can't take the address of a forward-declared only function.

As I explained, this isn't the actual code, which is rather more complex, using a macro to check the initialisation of many const function pointers. This is a cut-down version which shows the same problem. The original code was written (and works OK) using an earlier version of gcc, but updating to a later gcc gets this error.

Add -pedantic-errors to your gcc-11 compiler and it will reject it too for the same reason

"I could fix it by modifying the code, but ..." - Just roll up your sleeves and remove the static assertions one by one. Replace them with a runtime check if you really need to.

Hmmm, void testfunc(int testvar); is a tentative declaration.  (function might be inline later on.)  I doubt extern void testfunc(int testvar); will make any difference - yet worth trying.

@gebjon Why is static_assert(((uintptr_t)testfunc != 0), "error!!"); inside main() vs. at the global level?

If you have all these function pointers in an isolated part of your code, you could perhaps compile that part as C++ where constexpr function pointers initialized to point at a function actually works. Example

I wonder about the use of such a check. I think you cannot link successfully without resolving the reference, and then it is never zero (or NULL). Please [edit] your question to show a [mre] that produces the error message.

Why do you cast? Casts are by far a code smell of bad design or implementation.

Re "Why do you cast? Casts are by far a code smell of bad design or implementation.", Worse, that cast actually introduces an error. It checks if the bit pattern is zero, but the bit pattern of NULL is not required to be zero. Checking if a pointer is zero will check if it's NULL, but checking if a uintptr_t is zero does NOT check if it would be NULL as a pointer.

@Someprogrammerdude, "Pointers to functions can never be null" -- that's like saying "pointers to objects can never be null".  It's true, but trivial.  It's also borderline misleading, because pointers whose referenced type is a function type can, in general, be null, and those sometimes are loosely called "pointers to functions".  I think you mean that the pointer obtained by automatic conversion of a function identifier cannot be null, which is both true and more meaningful.

What should happen if testfunc is not defined anywhere?

Thanks for all the comments: just to clarify: the original code which exhibited the problem is spread across many source code files and deeply nested macros in an existing codebase. The original code used the static assertion to detect at build time if a const function pointer was initialised to NULL. I've been working on getting the code running on a different platform with a later gcc version. The code above is just the minimal snippet of code which exhibits the problem. @JohnBollinger's answer below explains the reason for the compiler error. Solution is to get rid of the static assertion.


I don't understand why I get this error as the function address is constant.

Yes, the function address is constant, in the sense that C defines it as an address constant, one of the forms of constant expression.  (C17 6.6/9)
But C places a stronger requirement on the expression in a static assertion: it must be an integer constant expression, and even though your expression has integer type, it does not qualify.  These are the requirements:

An integer constant expression shall have integer type and shall only
have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants,
character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer
constants, _Alignof expressions, and floating constants that are the
immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant
expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types,
except as part of an operand to the sizeof or _Alignof operator.

(C17 6.6/6)
Pointers are not among the operands the spec allows in integer constant expressions, neither in general nor as operands in cast (sub)expressions, except that they probably may appear in sizeof and _Alignof (sub)expressions.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Option 1: Remove the static assertions in question.  If your program contains (direct) calls to undefined functions, or if it attempts to take the address of an undefined function, then you will know it because of link errors.  On the other hand, until linking, your C implementation does not know whether there are any such calls, so even if it accepted static assertions such as those in your example, they would not tell you anything useful.
Option 2: Convert the static assertions to ordinary assertions. The expression in an ordinary assertion does not even have to be a constant expression, much less an integer constant expression.  Of course, these are not evaluated until runtime, and depending on how you build the program, they may be suppressed so that they are not evaluated at all.
Option 3: Stick with Gcc 11, since that apparently accepts the static assertions you have (which it is within its rights to do).  This is probably not a viable long-term strategy, but it can keep your builds working until you finish implementing option 1 or 2.
I looked for a command-line option in Gcc 12 that would provide the old behavior for such assertions, but if there is one, it eluded me.

Thanks for your analysis, much appreciated. That certainly explains the root cause of the problem. I thnk removing the static assertions and using a runtime check is the solution.
